# Measure time, milliseconds or microseconds for Windows C++

Tags: c++, windows, time, measure

How do you measure the execution time in milliseconds or microseconds in Windows C++?

I found many method one calling time(NULL), but it measures time in seconds only and the seconds clock() (clock_t) measure CPU time, not the actual time.

I found the function gettimeofday(Calendar time) mentioned in this paper: 
dropbox.com/s/k0zv8pck7ydbakz/1_7-PDF_thesis_2.pdf

This function is for Linux (compute time in milli and microseconds) and not Windows.

I found an alternative to it for Windows:
dropbox.com/s/ofo99b166l7e2gf/gettimeofday.txt

And this may be relevant: stackoverflow.com/questions/1861294/how-to-calculate-execution-time-of-a-code-snippet-in-c

Comment: Are you using C++ with CLR support?  Or Win32?  This question lacks a general understanding of the question.

Comment: I think this question is not well asked, but it's salvageable. +1 in the interest of fairness, and can someone help edit this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use the standard C++ [`<chrono>` library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

// long operation to time
long long fib(long long n) {
  if (n < 2) {
    return n;
  } else {
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
  }
}

int main() {
  auto start_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

  long long input = 32;
  long long result = fib(input);

  auto end_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  auto time = end_time - start_time;

  std::cout << "result = " << result << '\n';
  std::cout << "fib(" << input << ") took " <<
    time/std::chrono::milliseconds(1) << "ms to run.\n";
}
```

One thing to keep in mind is that using `<chrono>` enables type safe, generic timing code but to get that benefit you have use it a bit differently than you would use dumb, type-unsafe timing libraries that store durations and time points in types like `int`. Here's an answer that explains some specific usage scenarios and the differences between using untyped libraries and best practices for using chrono: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15839862/365496

---

The maintainer of Visual Studio's standard library implementation [has indicated](https://web.archive.org/web/20141212192132/https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/719443/) that the low resolution of `high_resolution_clock` has been fixed in VS2015 via the use of `QueryPerformanceCounter()`.

Comment: **Please note!** There is a bug in some versions of the `chrono` header supplied with Visual Studio. Please see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16299029/resolution-of-stdchronohigh-resolution-clock-doesnt-correspond-to-measureme). `QueryPerformanceCounter` is a way to get high resolution timing under Win32.

Comment: I can confirm that VS 2015 now uses `QueryPerformanceCounter` for `high_resolution_clock`. (Older VS versions just used `GetSystemTime` for all clocks.)

Comment: return statement in fib() is missing a semicolon

Comment: For completeness: Since VS2015, `high_resolution_clock` is an alias for `steady_clock`(it was an alias for `system_clock` until VS2012), and `steady_clock` uses QueryPerformanceCounter and QueryPerformanceFrequency. [Thus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/acquiring-high-resolution-time-stamps), as of VS2015, `high_resolution_clock` would be the highest resolution. **But,** just use std::chrono::steady_clock or std::chrono::system_clock *directly* instead of std::chrono::high_resolution_clock([ref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock)).

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the QPC/QPF APIs to get compute the execution time.  Invoke the code you want to between calls to [QueryPerformanceCounter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and then use [QueryPerformanceFrequency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644905%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to convert it from cycles to microseconds.

```
LARGE_INTEGER nStartTime;
LARGE_INTEGER nStopTime;
LARGE_INTEGER nElapsed;
LARGE_INTEGER nFrequency;

::QueryPerformanceFrequency(&nFrequency); 
::QueryPerformanceCounter(&nStartTime);

    SomethingToBeTimed();

::QueryPerformanceCounter(&nStopTime);
nElapsed.QuadPart = (nStopTime.QuadPart - nStartTime.QuadPart) * 1000000;
nElapsed.QuadPart /= nFrequency.QuadPart;
```

References:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn553408(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn553408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [`QueryPerformanceCounter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and related functions.